# get carrierwave image based on certain conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

How could one get a carrierwave image with has certain condition?

For example:

```
  image_tag @profile.photos.first.file_url(:profile)
```

Returns the first image but what If I want something like

```
@photo = Photo.where(:attachable_id => 1, :attachable_type => "Profile", :main => true)
```

:main => true means this is the profile picture a user has selected.

Also on a side note,

I have this function wich is a mess:

```
def show_avatar_thumb(id)
    @profile = User.find(id).profile rescue nil
    image_tag @profile.photos.first.file_url(:img_96x96)
  rescue
    image_tag ("/assets/avatars/img_96x96.png")
  end
```

Is there a way to improve this? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def show_avatar_thumb(id)
  begin
    user = User.find(id)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    image_tag ("/assets/avatars/img_96x96.png")
  else
    image_tag user.profile.photos.where(main: true).first.file_url(:img_96x96)
  end
end
```

I would pull `where(main: true)` out and put it in a model scope though.

Comment: that main: true doesent work the problem is i still have to dive into carrierwave it seems to have very vague helper methods only that way you can get the image